# Serializing form data with jquery

Tags: jquery, bulma

I have a form shown below that I'm trying to submit the data via jquery. It's not working.  The alert is blank. Note, I'm using bulma css framework.

HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Name</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" id="yrname" name="yrname" placeholder="Text input">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Username</label>
        <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input class="input is-success" type="text" id="usrname" name="usrname" placeholder="Text input" value="bulma">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control">
        <input class="button is-link" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    var data1 = $('form').serialize();
    alert('data1');
});
```

Comment: You alert a string `data1` instead of the variable. It should be `alert(data1)` (without the quotes).

Comment: @DouwedeHaan It must be TYPO while posting question

Comment: Darm!! completely didn't see the quotes!!... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
alert('data1');
```

With

```
alert(data1);
```

`data1` is a variable of js not a string!!

Comment: It must be TYPO while posting question. Even if its valid answer then vote to close as TYPO

Comment: Or it can be not? Let the OP decide because this kind of silly mistakes are not easily visible when its our code. :) @Satpal

Comment: Sure you can vote whatever you think is right. I have added it as an answer so OP can clearly see the difference. @Satpal